# Remark to theorem 9.8 from PMA Rudin

Tags: operator-theory

> Let $\Omega$ be the set of all invertible linear operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Mapping $A\mapsto A^{-1}$ is obviously a $1-1$ mapping of $\Omega$ onto $\Omega$.

This is excerpt from PMA Rudin.

But I can't prove that it's an injective mapping. Here is my thought: Let $A^{-1}=B^{-1}$ but $A\neq B$. Then exists $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax\neq Bx$ and any my attempts did not give any results. Can anyone show the proof please?

Any comment is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let $f$ be the map. Note that $f(f(A)) = A$, hence $f$ must be injective.

Comment: @copper.hat, Nice hint and this solves my problem! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are invertible and $A^{-1} = B^{-1}$, then
$$
I = A(A^{-1}) = AB^{-1},
$$
$$
B = IB = AB^{-1}B = A.
$$
So $B=A$.

Comment: +1 Good! This mapping is *onto* since for any $A^{-1}$ exists $A$ such that $A\mapsto A^{-1}$ because $A$ is invertible. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank a lot, dear Gyu Eun Lee for permanent help!